First and second condition in Hadamard's Well-posedness
From, e.g., Wikipedia we have
In mathematics, a well-posed problem is one for which the following properties hold:
1. The problem has a solution
2. The solution is unique
3. The solution's behavior changes continuously with the initial conditions
So, all these properties have to hold for a problem to be well-posed. But if we have 2. The solution is unique, does this not already imply 1. The problem has a solution?
